# Python PyGame - How do I use list information in order?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have code that scans an image in Python and gets the pixel data from it. It then generates lists with that data in.

e.g. [0,1,2,3] - X position of pixels, [0,0,0,0] - Y position of pixels, [221,0,34,102] - Red value of pixel, [2,100,3,102] - Green value of pixel, [121,25,4,120] - Blue value of pixel.

What I would like to do is use this information in order so I can draw tiles based on the RGB value at the X and Y coordinates.

So my question is: How do I read back items in a list in order so I can get the first items from one list into a new list, the second items from the list into another etc...

Desired output:

X,Y = [0,0], [1,0] etc...

R,G,B = [221,2,121], [0,100,25] etc..

Current code (probably not relevant):

```
import pygame, sys, os, math, time, pygame.surfarray

## SCREEN ##

pygame.init()
w,h = 800,600; cx,cy = w//2, h//2;
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h),0)
mapsurface = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h),1)

## IMPORT MAPS ##

map_1 = pygame.image.load("assets/maps/map1.png")

## Creates a new 'screen' for map to display (under game screen / invisible) ##

mapsurface.blit(map_1,(0,0))

class MapArray:

    map_array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(mapsurface)
    map_array_X = 0
    map_array_Y = 0
    map_array_output_colour_RED = [0]
    map_array_output_colour_GREEN = [0]
    map_array_output_colour_BLUE = [0]
    map_array_output_X = [0]
    map_array_output_Y = [0]
    DrawTiles = 0
    PRINT = 0

    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)

    def update(self,dt,key):

        colourRED_array = self.map_array[self.map_array_X,self.map_array_Y,0]
        colourGREEN_array = self.map_array[self.map_array_X,self.map_array_Y,1]
        colourBLUE_array = self.map_array[self.map_array_X,self.map_array_Y,2]

        ## MAP ARRAY SCAN - Gives X/Y coords and RGB value for each pixel in MAP ##

        if self.map_array_X <= 64 and colourBLUE_array < 255:
            self.map_array_X +=1
            self.map_array_output_colour_RED.append(colourRED_array)
            self.map_array_output_colour_GREEN.append(colourGREEN_array)
            self.map_array_output_colour_BLUE.append(colourBLUE_array)
            self.map_array_output_X.append(self.map_array_X)
            self.map_array_output_Y.append(self.map_array_Y)
            if self.map_array_X == 64 and colourBLUE_array < 255:
                self.map_array_Y+=1
                self.map_array_X = 0

        if colourBLUE_array < 255:
            print (self.map_array_output_X, self.map_array_output_Y, self.map_array_output_colour_RED, self.map_array_output_colour_GREEN, self.map_array_output_colour_BLUE)
            print ("")
        elif self.PRINT == 0: print ("Map Scan Finished!"); print ("");print ("Format: [Xpos_List] [Ypos_List] [colourRED_array] [colourGREEN_array] [colourBLUE_array]"); self.PRINT = 1; self.DrawTiles = 1;

        if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: pygame.quit(); sys.exit() #Quits Game#

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Map_Array = MapArray((0,0))

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(60)
    ## BACKGROUND ##
    screen.fill((100,100,100))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit();sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    Map_Array.update(dt, key)
```

Comment: "Current code (probably not relevant)". Code is **always** relevant =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost exacly why `zip` exists.

If you have:

```
image_colors = [[221,0,34,102], [2,100,3,102], [121,25,4,120]]
```

You can do:

```
combined_rgb = list(zip(*image_colors))
```

which will give you:

```
[(221, 2, 121), (0, 100, 25), (34, 3, 4), (102, 102, 120)]
```

Comment: Fantastic, I found the right implementation and it worked!